# KivyMD - Dropdown Menu: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' in

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, attributeerror, super, kivymd

I am stuck with this problem for quite a few days now. And also, now, I have a slight idea about this kind of error and that it has something to do with the python file trying to access an element (Dropdown menu) using its **id** in the kivy string.

But since I am new to OOP, I cannot figure out what exactly has to be done.

Here's the code:

*The arrangement of elements in the code is going to be changed later. So don't worry about that.

All I need is to get the dropdown menu working in this kind of code (i.e., where there are multiple screens within a screen manager, and each screen is represented by a separate class.)

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton
    
    
    class MenuScreen(Screen):
        pass
    
    
    class ProScreen(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            
            menu_items = [{"text": f"{i}"} for i in ["XML","Bootstrap","Mysql","None"]]
            self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
                                       caller=self.ids.drop_item,
                                       items=menu_items,
                                       width_mult=4,
                                       callback=self.set_item)   
            
            self.menu.bind(on_release=self.set_item)
                
        def set_item(self, instance_menu_item):
            self.ids.drop_item.text = instance_menu_item.text
            self.menu.dismiss()
            
        def display_selection(self):
            select1 = self.ids.drop_item.text                
            #lx = self.root.ids.lx.text
            #res = ["the dropdown menu selection is:",]
            print (select1)
        
        def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
            self.app.title = "Slab"
            
        def show_data(self, *args):
            ly = self.ids.ly.text                 
            #lx = self.root.ids.lx.text
            res = ["hi we are bts" ,float(ly)]
            print (res)
            res2 = float(ly)+1
            self.ids.res11.text = str(res)
            print (res2)
    
    class UploadScreen(Screen):
        pass
    
    
    class DemoApp18(MDApp):
    
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
            #self.scr22 = Builder.load_string(temp_kv.KV)
            self.screen_manager = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
            
            self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
            self.screen_manager.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menupage'))
            self.screen_manager.add_widget(ProScreen(name='pro'))
            self.screen_manager.add_widget(UploadScreen(name='upload'))
            
        def build(self):
            return self.screen_manager
            
    
    DemoApp18().run()
```

And the Kivy string is called "screen_helper", and is shared below:

```
"""
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProScreen:
    UploadScreen:
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menupage'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Pro'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'pro'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Upload'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'upload'
    
<ProScreen>:
    name: 'pro'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Pro'
        halign: 'center'
        
    MDTextField:
        id: ly
        hint_text: "Enter longer span of slab"
        helper_text: "(should be in m)"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        icon_right: "android"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        size_hint_x:None
        width:250
        halign: "center"
        valign: "top"
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Pro'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: 
            #root.manager.current = 'menupage'
            #app.screen_manager.pro.show_data()
            root.show_data()
            
    MDLabel:
        #text: "Enter details:"
        theme_font_styles: "H1"
        id: res11
        #halign: "center"
        
    MDDropDownItem:
        id: drop_item
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        text: 'Select OPtion'
        on_release: app.menu.open()
        
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: btn1
        text: "Display"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .75}
        on_release: 
            root.display_selection()
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menupage'

<UploadScreen>:
    name: 'upload'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Upload'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menupage'
        
"""
```

DropDownMenu is such an important part of what I am creating. I can't even just replace it with some other element.
Please suggest me **any** way to make this work

Oh! and the error message appears like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

KeyError: 'drop_item'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\kmd_inpython2.py", line 212, in <module>
    DemoApp18().run()

  File "C:\Users\kmd_inpython2.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.screen_manager = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

  File "C:\Users\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
    rule_children=rule_children)

  File "C:\Users\builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
    child = cls(__no_builder=True)

  File "C:\Users\kmd_inpython2.py", line 115, in __init__
    caller=self.ids.drop_item,

  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail of the error (`AttributeError`)? I believe it would help others in answer your question.

Comment: sorry. yes. just added the error details.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem.